# Mysql group_contact with conditions

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I think this is rare and not sure if posiblle.

I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_product,GROUP_CONCAT(id_tag  ORDER BY id_tag  ) AS producto  
FROM ps_product_tag  
where id_product = '194'
GROUP BY id_product";
```

And i get this result:

```
Array ( [id_product] => 194 [producto] => 36,190,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,284,286,287,289 )
```

What i need is to do make some filter the id_tag resulting array with multiple where conditions.

```
WHERE t.`id_tag` = '275'
AND t.`id_tag` = '282'
AND t.`id_tag` = '286'
AND t.`id_tag` = '289'
```

But i'm not able to doit.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Do you mean 'id_tag' = '275' OR t.id_tag = '282' ... ? If not, how can the id_tag could be  '282' and '275' the same time?

Comment: Hi. I mean the tags 275 and 282 must to be in the array. Both.  Thnx for your help :)

Comment: Please do not retitle the question - rather *accept the answer* - click the checkmark outline beside the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
SELECT
    id_product,
    GROUP_CONCAT(id_tag ORDER BY id_tag) AS producto,
    COUNT(*) as `n`
FROM ps_product_tag
WHERE id_tag IN ('275', '282', '286', '287')
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING `n`=4
```

Comment: Hi awn. It seems it's working. I realy appreciate your help and your knowledge!

Comment: You only ensure that the product has one of the four tags and in total 4 tags

Comment: @Bonja Not quite.  The WHERE clause happens before the GROUP BY and filters out all other tags.  The only way this will fail is if there are multiple copies of a given tag for a given id_product.

Comment: Do you show all tags for the matched products, or only the in tags? Because the others rows where filtered before group them

Comment: Ok, I thought that he needed the products with the 4 tags, and for these products show all the tags. But if only these tags are needed, it's different

Comment: Hi to all. @awn Your sql works perfect. Thnx. @ borja, also thank you for your help and to all people. It seems i'm going to be able to do my job.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `(id_product, id_tag)` is unique, try this:

```
SELECT id_product
FROM ps_product_tag
WHERE id_tag IN ('275', '282', '286', '287')
GROUP BY id_product
HAVING COUNT(id_tag) = 4
```

Comment: Hi Mark. I have no result. Trying with one condition but still not working

Comment: It should have been id_tag instead of id_product. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thnx! Thnx! Thnx! Thnx! It works great!!!  I've been 4 hours with this before asking.

Comment: Note that this does not require all 4 tags exist in the result set before it's collapsed by the GROUP BY. It just requires that all rows match at least one of the four.

Comment: Hi Dan. So its not what i need. I need the 4 tags to exist :( Do you know if at least is it possible? Thnx

Comment: @user - Try adding `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_tag) = 4`. NB: The `DISTINCT` probably isn't needed if you have appropriate constraints to prevent duplicate entries. This is called [Relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Answer (score 1):

If you need the products with the four tags, you can use:

```
SELECT
      p.id_product,
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.id_tag ORDER BY id_tag) AS producto,
  FROM ps_product_tag as p INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT id_product  
      FROM ps_product_tag
      WHERE id_tag IN ('275', '282', '286', '287')
    GROUP BY id_product HAVING COUNT(*) = 4) as alltags
    ON alltags.id_product = p.id_product
GROUP BY id_product
```